# Provisioning Nymi band from Android app

Tags: android, errno

I am trying to provision the Nymi band from my android app. I am using the sample code from the Nymi Android SDK 2.0 (Can be downloaded from [here:](https://www.nymi.com/dev/)). I removed all the code related to the Nymulator(Nymi band emulator). I want to test the provisioning with the real Nymi band. However,when I click the provision button, the app get crashed. I tried to debug it with the exception breakpoints and I got the "getsockopt errno 88" error in my debugger:

I am attaching the screenshot too.[image]

I did some research on google , and found that the errno 88 is

```
#define ENOTSOCK    88  /* Socket operation on non-socket */
```

During the app launch, I see the following message in the Debug Console:

```
Connected to the target VM, address: 'localhost:8604', transport: 'socket'
```

which I think,the connection to socket is fine. I am not sure,what makes the socket connection go wrong later.

This is what I see in my LOgCat after I click the provision button:(I am posting only some part of the error message,because the error message in Logcat is way too long)
[image]

Edit: I added some breakpoints,and I found where the app is crashing. I found this code:

```
    try {
        System.loadLibrary("_nymi_sdk_net");
        _loaded = true;
    } catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError var6) {
        return false;
    }
```

At system.load library, I am getting the error.

Edit 2: I changed the libraries from net to native ,as net is for emulators and native is for device. This time new error occurs at the same line:`System.loadLibrary("_nymi_sdk");`

Screenshot:[image]

Comment: The Debug console only shows that the IDE is connected to the phone, and in fact, it has nothing to do with your application. Check the Logcat view instead, that is where the phone logs are streamed to.

Comment: I added the logcat output. Please see.

Comment: I've found something interesting in the SDK and rewritten my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(Disclaimer: I know nothing of this SDK or the band, and this answer is just a speculation. And I've deleted my earlier answer as it was a missed shot in the dark.)*

There is a minor hint in the SDK's README.md:

> ### Prerequisites:
>
> - Android Development:
>
>   - [...]
>   - To use the BasicExample app with a Nymi Band, the NCL library in Examples\BasicExample\libs must be replaces with the native library in
>       NCL\native\libs

You must remove all files and folders from `BasicExample\libs` and copy all files from `NCL\native\libs` there instead.

*(I wonder why they didn't emphasize this much harder...)*

So the libs folder should contain the following folders and files:

[image: Screenshot of the file tree in the example project]

Comment: I tired your solution,it didnt worked. The app still getting crashed with the same error.

Comment: Well, that's too bad. The other string that could be null is the app name. You didn't change "NCLExample", did you?

Comment: i am updating my question . please look at it

Comment: i am trying to do that, i removed the net.jar file and replaced it with native.jar file, but somehow the native.jar file isn't expanding and showing the NCL lib files

Comment: but the files still exists in the native.jar file

Comment: The insides of the jar files look the same, but the actual bytecode is different. You shouldn't unpack them though. On the other hand, you have to replace all folders (`arm64-v8a`, etc.) too.

Comment: yes i did....and here comes the new error!!! The error occurs at the same line at System.library(nymi_sdk) but this time the error is "open" . See the Edit.

Comment: Does it mean, I am missing the _nimi_sdk file?

Comment: Yes, that's what it means. Please double-check that all files are in the right place (see my newest edit).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81330/discussion-between-vzsg-and-t-77).